# add offset to multiple columns in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-columns

I am trying to plot from a multiple column file where the first column is the x and the rest should be y columns like this:

```
plot for[col=2:36:1] 'datafile' using 1:col with lines lc rgb 'black' notitle
```

This works fine but what I want to do is to offset all the y columns by a constant value.

I tried something like this:

```
plot for[col=2:36:1] 'datafile' using 1:(col-const) with lines lc rgb 'black' notitle
```

but it doesn't work (it seems to plot the difference between the variable col and the constant value const).

Is there a way to do this? I have found here how to offset the y column for a 2 column file (or a specific column in a file)

```
plot 'otherdatafile' using 1:($2-const) with lines
```

but can this be expanded for my case?

Thanks in advance,

Lucian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 1:(column(col)-const) should work

Comment: that did it! thank you very much! this should be marked as solved and make it easy for people to find because this feature is not obvious at all in gnuplot documentation!

Comment: It's quite prominently mentioned at the beginning of the `using` doc,  http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-324

Comment: thank you for pointing that out to me! I did read that bit but I couldn't understand the significance of it! Now it makes sense.